# Changing the date on calendar after choosing it using datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have this code and want to link fullcalendar with date/timepicker bootstrap

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div id="datetimepicker1"></div><div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: show us in jsfiddle.

Comment: Do you want to open `fullCalender` when a date selected on bootstrap datepicker? something like this https://jsbin.com/wajopom/edit?js,output